# null response on saveAsync on backendless 4

Tags: android, backendless

I am having some problem with backendless 4.

I have this method to save a obj.

```
private void registrar() {
mEndereco.setNomeDaRua(mEditTextEndereco.getText().toString());

mEndereco.setBairro(mEditTextBairro.getText().toString());

mEndereco.setCep(mEditTextCEP.getText().toString());

mEndereco.setNumero(mEditTextNumero.getText().toString());

mEndereco.setComplemento(mEditTextComplemento.getText().toString());

mEndereco.setCidade(mEditTextCidade.getText().toString());

mEndereco.setEstado("RJ");

mEndereco.setReferencia(mEditTextReferencia.getText().toString());

ArrayList<Endereco> enderecos = new ArrayList<>();

enderecos.add(mEndereco);

mPessoa.setEnderecoDoCliente(enderecos);

Log.d(TAG, "Usuário final: " + mPessoa.toString());

try

{

mEndereco.saveAsync(new AsyncCallback<Endereco>() {

@Override

public void handleResponse(Endereco response) {

Log.d(TAG, response.getNomeDaRua());

}

@Override

public void handleFault(BackendlessFault fault) {

}

});

}

catch ( Exception e )

{

Toast.makeText( this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

return;

}

}
```

the class is:

```
public class Endereco implements Parcelable {

@SuppressWarnings("unused")

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Endereco> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Endereco>() {

@Override

public Endereco createFromParcel(Parcel in) {

return new Endereco(in);

}

@Override

public Endereco[] newArray(int size) {

return new Endereco[size];

}

};

protected Endereco(Parcel in) {

numero = in.readString();

ownerId = in.readString();

referencia = in.readString();

complemento = in.readString();

nomeDaRua = in.readString();

objectId = in.readString();

estado = in.readString();

cidade = in.readString();

long tmpUpdated = in.readLong();

updated = tmpUpdated != -1 ? new Date(tmpUpdated) : null;

long tmpCreated = in.readLong();

created = tmpCreated != -1 ? new Date(tmpCreated) : null;

bairro = in.readString();

cep = in.readString();

}

private String numero;

private String ownerId;

private String referencia;

private String complemento;

private String nomeDaRua;

private String objectId;

private String estado;

private String cidade;

private Date updated;

private Date created;

private String bairro;

private String cep;

public Endereco() {

}

public static Endereco findById(String id) {

return Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).findById(id);

}

public static void findByIdAsync(String id, AsyncCallback<Endereco> callback) {

Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).findById(id, callback);

}

public static Endereco findFirst() {

return Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).findFirst();

}

public static void findFirstAsync(AsyncCallback<Endereco> callback) {

Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).findFirst(callback);

}

public static Endereco findLast() {

return Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).findLast();

}

public static void findLastAsync(AsyncCallback<Endereco> callback) {

Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).findLast(callback);

}

public static List<Endereco> find(DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder) {

return Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).find(queryBuilder);

}

public static void findAsync(DataQueryBuilder queryBuilder, AsyncCallback<List<Endereco>> callback) {

Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).find(queryBuilder, callback);

}

public String getNumero() {

return numero;

}

public void setNumero(String numero) {

this.numero = numero;

}

public String getOwnerId() {

return ownerId;

}

public String getReferencia() {

return referencia;

}

public void setReferencia(String referencia) {

this.referencia = referencia;

}

public String getComplemento() {

return complemento;

}

public void setComplemento(String complemento) {

this.complemento = complemento;

}

public String getNomeDaRua() {

return nomeDaRua;

}

public void setNomeDaRua(String nomeDaRua) {

this.nomeDaRua = nomeDaRua;

}

public String getObjectId() {

return objectId;

}

public String getEstado() {

return estado;

}

public void setEstado(String estado) {

this.estado = estado;

}

public String getCidade() {

return cidade;

}

public void setCidade(String cidade) {

this.cidade = cidade;

}

public java.util.Date getUpdated() {

return updated;

}

public java.util.Date getCreated() {

return created;

}

public String getBairro() {

return bairro;

}

public void setBairro(String bairro) {

this.bairro = bairro;

}

public String getCep() {

return cep;

}

public void setCep(String cep) {

this.cep = cep;

}

public Endereco save() {

return Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).save(this);

}

public void saveAsync(AsyncCallback<Endereco> callback) {

Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).save(this, callback);

}

public Long remove() {

return Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).remove(this);

}

public void removeAsync(AsyncCallback<Long> callback) {

Backendless.Data.of(Endereco.class).remove(this, callback);

}

@Override

public int describeContents() {

return 0;

}

@Override

public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

dest.writeString(numero);

dest.writeString(ownerId);

dest.writeString(referencia);

dest.writeString(complemento);

dest.writeString(nomeDaRua);

dest.writeString(objectId);

dest.writeString(estado);

dest.writeString(cidade);

dest.writeLong(updated != null ? updated.getTime() : -1L);

dest.writeLong(created != null ? created.getTime() : -1L);

dest.writeString(bairro);

dest.writeString(cep);

}

}
```

When i debug, at

Log.d(TAG, "Usuário final: " + mPessoa.toString());

i have the Endereco class all filled right.

But, afther mEndereco.saveAsync(new AsyncCallback() {...

At: Log.d(TAG, response.getNomeDaRua()), i got a null at response

I am migrating to 3.x to 4.x, and done all change at init ands keys.

Obs.:

Pessoa mPessoa = new Pessoa();

Endereco mEndereco = new Endereco();

At global of the class.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the behavior you describe: when I save an object with a bunch of String properties, I get the same properties with values in response. It will help a lot if you prepare a [minimal verifiable sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I could run it and see the same problem. Also, if the problem is actually in your code (which is most probably), odds are you'll find it much earlier when making that sample.

Comment: oh, it seems you've already solved the problem on [the support forum](http://support.backendless.com/topic/null-response-on-saveasync) :)

Comment: Ye, support help me.